# Magento custom where condition

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a custom collection with custom eav attributes. I'm trying to create custom query to filter my custom collection. "Where" condition which I'm going to create should look like bellow:

```
(start_date <= $current_date AND active_to >= $current_date) OR unlimited = 1
```

There is my code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('campaigns/campaign_collection')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
$collection->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("(start_at <= '" . $current_date . "' AND active_to >= '" . $current_date . "') OR unlimited = 1"));
```

But in that case I'm getting an error that column start_at not found.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using addFieldToFilter(), something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('campaigns/campaign_collection')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'start_date', 'gteq' => $current_date),array('attribute' => 'unlimited', 'eq' => '1')))
        ->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'active_to', 'lteq' => $current_date),array('attribute' => 'unlimited', 'eq' => '1')));
```

Calling the function two times subsequently causes it to act like an 'AND' operator. The 'array('attribute' => 'unlimited', 'eq' => '1')' should be the 'OR' operator.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've already tried this solution as well, but in some reason I'm getting only campaigns that have unlimited field set to 1

Comment: In what format is the date stored in de database, and what is the format of $current_date ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to print the query you are getting by 
$collection->printLogQuery(true);
This will allow to get query that your collection is making thus you can directly verify in database. Hope this helps